# Edit entity in Ef - UnitOfWork

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, unit-of-work

I am using this template for my project

```
   public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
        int SaveChanges();
        void RejectChanges();
        DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
    }
```

Implementation:

```
  public   class BookStoreDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork

  {

    public DbSet<Categori> Categoris { get; set; }


    public new DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Entry(entity);

    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Controler:

```
 public class CategoriController : Controller
   {

    private IUnitOfWork _uw;

    private ICategoriService _categoriService;


    public CategoriController(IUnitOfWork uw,ICategoriService categoriservice )
    {
        _uw = uw;
        _categoriService = categoriservice;
    }




   public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        var categori = _categoriService.Find(i => i.Id == id);
        if (categori == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(categori);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Categori categori)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

              _uw.Entry(categori).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _uw.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View(categori);
    }
}
```

Repository or Servis layer:

```
 public interface IGenericService<T> : IDisposable where T : class
    {
    void Add(T entity);

    void Delete(T entity);
    T Find(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    IList<T> GetAll();
    IList<T> GetAll(Func<T, bool> predicate);


    }




 public interface ICategoriService : IGenericService<DomainClasses.Models.Categori>
   {

   }
```

impliment repository:

```
 public class EfGenericService<TEntity> : IGenericService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected IUnitOfWork _uow;
    protected IDbSet<TEntity> _tEntities;



    public EfGenericService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _tEntities = _uow.Set<TEntity>();
    }


    public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        _tEntities.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        _tEntities.Remove(entity);
    }

    public TEntity Find(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _tEntities.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IList<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _tEntities.ToList();
    }

    public IList<TEntity> GetAll(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _tEntities.Where(predicate).ToList();
    }



 public class EfCategoriService : EfGenericService<Categori>,ICategoriService
{
      public EfCategoriService(IUnitOfWork uow)
        : base(uow)
      {
    }


}
```

Global.asax

```
 private static void InitStructureMap()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(
            x =>
                {
                    x.For<IUnitOfWork>().HttpContextScoped().Use(() => new BookStoreDbContext());
                     x.ForRequestedType<ServiceLayer.Interfaces.ICategoriService>()
                     .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<EfCategoriService>();

}
```

But I get this error when update entity:

Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries

Please help me to resolve this error?

Comment: You are using some type of Dependency Injection? Could you show how you've configured your IUnitOfWork and ICategoriService for DI?

Comment: Yes, this is done
I've updated the code and dependence on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only relevant lines in your snippets are:

```
_uw.Entry(categori).State = EntityState.Modified;
_uw.SaveChanges();
```

Now, look at the exception you get:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded.

- Does setting the entity state to `Modified` *insert* an entity? No.
- Does it *delete* an entity? No.
- Does it *update* an entity? Yes.
- May the entity that EF tries to update have been *deleted*? Well, perhaps. How to check that? When an entity is deleted the database must know the key in order to know which row to delete. To confirm if the key is correct **use a debugger in your controller post action, inspect the key value of `categori` that is passed into the method. Does it have the expected value? If not, you probably have a problem in your view or with binding the form and route values to the `categori` model.** If yes, check in the database if the entity with that key is in the database table. If yes, next point.
- May the entity have been *modified*? It could happen that EF "thinks" it has been modified  in the database (even if it hasn't) if you have marked another property in your `Categori` model as a concurrency token. If that property has changed in the database *or in the view* between loading the entity in the GET request and reattaching (setting the state to `Modified`) and `SaveChanges` in the POST request you'll get a concurrency violation.

Priority has the test in bold above because it is the most likely cause of the problem in my opinion. If it turns out that the key doesn't have the expected value better ask a new question because it will be a pure ASP.NET MVC question that has nothing to do with EF and your UOW and service architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
In the above example I am doing delete and add.
But I am facing this error when editing.
I even Get method would be to edit it.
I placed it in the code above.

Comment: @MehRad: I am not sure if you understood me right. The important thing to check is what value the `categori` **Id** has when it enters the Edit POST action `public ActionResult Edit(Categori categori)`. YOU must check this, I cannot know it from the code you are showing.